# how to slide images using viewpager and fragment

Tags: android

i want to make an android app of book...i want to slide images with touch....plz tell in which folder i have to place images....which code is suitable to slide images 
i tried this code...but this is not working

```
package com.example.avoidingpoliceconflicts;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.policeofficers.avoidingpoliceconflicts.R;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    PagerAdapter PagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    abstract class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super();

        }
         public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
             switch(pos) {

             case 0: return Fragment1.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
             case 1: return fragment2.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
             case 2: return Fragment1.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
             case 3: return fragment2.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
             case 4: return fragment2.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
             default: return fragment2.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
             }
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
             return 5;
         }       
    }enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code and there are a lot of examples available, just Google :)

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question difficult to answer in a meanigful way, because your problem is unclear: _not working_ is not a sufficient explanation. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27689483/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example in which I took images from an array buildInfoBean you can use as per your requirements...

```
viewpager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewpager.setAdapter(new MypagesAdapter());

    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
            viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mIndicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


    //Adapter for pager

    class MypagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter
        {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {

                return buildInfoBean.buildingImages.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                View page = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewpager, null);
                final ImageView im = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

                Log.e("Images",buildInfoBean.buildingImages.get(position).imageUrl);
                ImageLoader.getInstance(getActivity()).DisplayImage(buildInfoBean.buildingImages.get(position).imageUrl, im);


                ((ViewPager) container).addView(page, 0);
                return page;
            } 
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arg0==(View)arg1;
            }
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
                object=null;
            }

        }
```